# Reading to an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, multidimensional-array

I am trying to read an excel sheet using C# and store each row into an array. I am able to open the file but the code I am using currently  reads to an "2D-Object" array  but I would like to read the info into 1D-string arrays.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Reference to Excel Application.
    Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();

    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Path.GetFullPath("excelpractice1.xlsx"));

    // Get the first worksheet.
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
    // Get the range of cells which has data.
    Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

    // Get an object array of all of the cells in the worksheet with their values.
    object[,] valueArray = (object[,])xlRange.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
    // Close the Workbook.
    xlWorkbook.Close(false);

    // Relase COM Object by decrementing the reference count.
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

    // Close Excel application.
    xlApp.Quit();

    // Release COM object.
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);

    Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

`

Comment: And how would you map your 2D array to a 1D string array? Just concatenate each row? Explain what you are trying to do better.

Comment: I am basically trying to create a program where I can take one persons information off a small excel sheet and add it to a master excel sheet.

Comment: May [this](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/blob/master/readme.markdown) help?

Comment: @Cscience18: That really didn't make your question any clearer. It seems the excel part isn't the issue here, the issue is how to extra a single row from a 2D array into a 1D array and then convert that into a string. If that's what you are trying to do, then it ought to be simple enough.

Comment: @Matt If it was simple to me then I would not be asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was trying to comment only. =X
But did it worked for you anyway? [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/blob/master/readme.markdown) is a great library for manipulate spreadsheets!
Please, let me know if has any doubt yet.

=)